# Blank page before long table

Tags: tables, blank-page

I want to add a page-long table using:

```
 \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{| p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{4cm}|}
        %long table
        \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
```

However, this adds an unwanted blank page before the table.
What can I do to fix it?

UPDATE: Here is the template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.95}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Uncomment to remove all indentation from paragraphs


\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}



 \begin{document}

 \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{| p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{4cm}|}
        %long table
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
        1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline

        \end{tabular}
 \end{center}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable that we can see the resulting blank page ...

Comment: The problem could be occurring because of some code elements that occur before `\begin{center}`, because the `center` environment is -- contrary to your assertion -- taller than `\pageheight`, or because of something else entirely. We won't know which one, unless you post a fully compilable example.

Comment: The table is too large for the remaining space on the page, so LaTeX starts a new page in the hope it will fit. This doesn't work, of course, because the table is too large for the page itself.

Comment: @cfr so how can I split it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table is too long to fit on a page. LaTeX sees how much space is left on the current page before typesetting the table and compares this with the size of the entire `center` environment. Because it obviously finds there isn't enough space, it starts a new page before attempting to typeset the material. Obviously this doesn't help as the material is too large for the page and not just the remaining space on this page. But LaTeX doesn't know that.

To automatically split the table between pages, we can use something like `longtable`.

We don't need the `center` environment in this case.

However, the table is also too wide for the page.

A good solution is probably to load `geometry` which will set slightly more sensible margins.

Then the table fits the width and `longtable` splits it over a page break:

[image: split table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable,geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{4cm}|}
  %long table
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This is a fairly ugly way to format tables. I'd recommend looking at how publication quality tables are formatted and the guidelines in the `booktabs` manual. For example:

[image: booktabs]

improves things, although it could be further improved in light of the actual content of the table in the actual document. (E.g. the final column looks too wide here, but that is probably a result of the dummy content.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{*{3}{p{3cm}}p{4cm}}
  \toprule\endhead
  \bottomrule\endfoot
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
  1000000 & 4x4 & T(t)=Tmax/t & finds the solution\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Lovely answer! `longtable` saved my day! Thank you!